# How to pass * as an argument with jQuery to be validated in the Laravel controller?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-6, sweetalert

I've tried passing through using string (`teachers_remark.*`) from what I searched, but it is not validated in the controller. I expected it to return an error, but it is successfully saved instead.

Need help, I'm a beginner in jQuery.

This is my jQuery:

```
var students_id = $('#students').val();
var teachers_id = $('#teachers').val();

var teacherArray = $('#my_teachers_remarks input').map(function () {
    return {
        "value": this.value,
    }
}).get();
sessionStorage['teachers'] = JSON.stringify(teacherArray);

var teachers_remark_arr = [];
teachers_remark_arr = sessionStorage['teachers'];

event.preventDefault();
swal({
    title: "{{ __('Are you sure?') }}",
    text: "{{ __('No further changes allowed.') }}",
    icon: "warning",
    buttons: true,
    dangerMode: true,
})
.then(function(willAssign) {
    if (willAssign) {
        return axios.post(route('students.report'), {
            students: students_id,
            teachers: teachers_id,
            'teachers_remark.*': teachers_remark_arr,
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.status === 'ERROR'){
                swal({
                    title: "Error",
                    text: response.data.errors,
                    icon: "error"
                }).then(function(){
                    location.reload();
                });
            }

        if (response.data.status === 'SUCCESS'){
            swal("Success", response.data.message , "success");
        }
    })
```

This is my Controller:

```
$this->validate(
    $request,
    [
        'students'       => ['required'],
        'teachers'             => ['required'],
        'teachers_remark.*'   => ['required'],
    ],
    [
        'students.required' => 'There is no students selected.',
        'teachers.required' => 'There is no teachers selected.',
        'teachers_remark.*.required' => 'You must include remarks',
    ]
);
```